# How to add non Latin letters in JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a very basic Jasper Report as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.2-75c5e90a222ab406e416cbf590a5397028a52de3  -->
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="xxxx" >
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="something"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.property.dataset.dialog.DatasetDialog.sash.w1" value="354"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.property.dataset.dialog.DatasetDialog.sash.w2" value="632"/>
        <parameter name="idorder" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select * from something    where somthing = $P{idorder}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="TITRE" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="TITRE"/>
        </field>        
        <detail>
            <band height="802" splitType="Stretch">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <textField textAdjust="ScaleFont">
                    <reportElement uuid="05234b42-f511-431a-8891-1ac49a6758ab"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font fontName="Arial" size="22" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TITRE}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

I need the title to be in Chinese characters. So I set the property `pdfEncoding="Identity-H"`.

The report works properly on JasperSoft Studio. However when uploading the report on JasperServer, I'm getting the error :

```
    There was an error on the server. Try again or contact site administrators. 
    Could not load the following font: 
    pdfFontName: Helvetica
    pdfEncoding: Identity-H
    isPdfEmbedded : false
```

I don't understand where this error is coming from since I do not use the font Helvetica at all in my report.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`pdfEncoding` by itself is not enough to display non Latin text in PDF.

You need to find a font that includes Chinese characters, create a font extension for it and use it in the report.

The [Unicode sample](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/tree/master/jasperreports/demo/samples/unicode/src/arphic) included in JasperReports uses for instance AR PL KaitiM GB font.

In Jaspersoft Studio you would define the font extension under Settings/Jaspersoft Studio/Fonts.  Make sure you check the "Embed this font in PDF" flag and set Identity-H as Pdf Encoding.

To add the font in JasperServer, you can export the font extension as a jar from Studio and then add the jar under WEB-INF/lib in your server deployment.